# How to sum digits in String till specific index in functional way

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-stream, java-11

I want to sum digits from eg. `String` like "153" till index 2 and receive result `6` because of 1+5=6.
In a normal way, I would use the classic loop solution like with check whether current index is lower than 2:

```
static int sum(String s){
       int sum = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < s.length() ; i++){
            if( Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i)) ){
                sum = sum + Character.getNumericValue(s.charAt(i));
            }
        }
        return sum;
}
```

Above approach works as it should but I want to rewrite this logic to Java `stream` approach.

I have an implementation like:

```
  public static int sumDigitsTillIndex(String number) {
    return IntStream.range(0, number.length())
        .filter(i -> i < 2)
        .map(number::charAt)
        .sum();
  }
```

and for this with argument 153 I am receiving 102 what is a surprise for me.

I have found another, smiliar solution like:

```
   return String
    .valueOf(number)
    .chars()
    .map(Character::getNumericValue)
    .sum();
```

which is summing numbers properly but with additional `filter` method like:
`.filter(index -> number.charAt(index) < 2)`
I am receiving 
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 49`

I will be grateful for suggestion on how to fix these two above solutions and receive functional approach which will sum up digits from String till particular index.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do:

```
number.chars()
      .limit(2)
      .map(Character::getNumericValue)
      .sum();
```

or

```
number.substring(0, 2)
            .chars()
            .map(Character::getNumericValue)
            .sum();
```

Comment: @Haji J Thank you so much for a response. One simple thing, what in case if I would add additional `predicate` via filter method, for instance sum only odd numbers or something? I added .filter(n -> n == 1) for your first example but now it's returning 0. I don't know I am so tired today or I can not see sth crucial? Cheers

Comment: add after mapping `..map(Character::getNumericValue).filter(n->n%2==1)...`

Comment: Gosh, enough for today, typical blonde moment. Thank you so much for the response.

Answer (score 2):

`String.charAt(int)` returns a character which you then box to a `Character`. Also, instead of `filter` you can use `limit`. Like,

```
return IntStream.range(0, number.length())
        .limit(2)
        .map(i -> Character.digit(number.charAt(i), 10))
        .sum();
```

Which gives `6` for `"153"` as requested.

Comment: Thank you so much for a response. It's working fine but readability is a little bit more complex than in case Hadi J solution. Regardless, thumb up :)